# How do I get 2 divs within another div centred and floated to the right?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have 2 divs on my page that I want to appear with one centred relative to the page (the page title) and the other floated to the right (a navigation bar). I can't get the title centred relative to the page. The best I can do is have it centred relative to the space remaining to the left of the navigation bar.

This demonstrates the problem I'm having.

```
<style>
  .page {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: red;
  }
  .navbar {
     float: right;
   }
  .title {
      text-align: center;
  }
</style>


<div class='page'>
  <div class='navbar'>
    navbar
  </div>
  <div class='title'>
    <h1>TITLE GOES HERE</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: I don't think you can do that without specifying another div on the left which would just occupy space. If you assign equal widths to each you can then center the title of the one in the middle.

Comment: That's a good idea. I could even assign the width to the left div dynamically using jquery if I couldn't guarantee the width of the right div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dcrodjer/3Q3UE/)?

```
<style>
  .page {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: red;
    position:relative;
  }
  .navbar {
    position:absolute;
    right:2px;
   }
  .title {
      text-align: center;
  }
</style>


<div class='page'>
  <div class='navbar'>
    navbar
  </div>
  <div class='title'>
    <h1>TITLE GOES HERE</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I'd tried something like that but couldn't quite make it work (the right property is what I was stuffing up).

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but could you edit the contents of the jsFiddle into the body of this answer?